# How to update existing list

Tags: java, list

Revised question:

suppose I have an obect emp and inside this object emp I also have a list for salary. Now I have to update the salary list inside this object emp with another list of salary.
Meaning that I have to add all new salary items inside the old emp salary list. My code is as below:

```
     emp.getResults().stream()
            .map(someanotherObject::Salaries)
            .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .filter(emp -> emp.empId == 5005).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .addAll(newSalaryListToBeAdded);
```

If I run this code, there were no issue but the salary list inside the emp object do not updated.

---

I am trying to add a new item on my existing list but could not. While I debug, it shows the return as true but eventually the new items did not add into the list.

My sample code are as below:

Employee employee1 = new Employee(5001,"BOB",financeDept.getDepartment_name());
Employee employee2 = new Employee(5002,"SAM",financeDept.getDepartment_name());

Employee employee3 = new Employee(5003,"SAM",hrDept.getDepartment_name());

Employee empToBeAdded = new Employee(5007,"TOM",hrDept.getDepartment_name());

List oldEmpList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(employee1,employee2, employee3));

List employeeListToBeAdded = new ArrayList<>();
employeeListToBeAdded.add(empToBeAdded);

oldEmpList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).addAll(new ArrayList<>(employeeListToBeAdded));
//This is not adding the new item into the old list.

Please note that I have to do some stream, map and filter on my old list.

Therefore question would be how to add new list item on an old list by doing some stream, map and filter the old list?

Comment: In your last line, you're creating a list, adding a bunch of stuff into it, and then not keeping any reference to it. What list are you trying to add stuff to?

Comment: Do you simply want to add all items from `emplyeeeListToBeAdded` to the `oldEmpList`? If so, just do `oldEmpList.addAll(employeeListToBeAdded)`. "_Please note that I have to do some stream, map and filter on my old list._" - then you will have to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Question has been updated, that was a typo.

Comment: @maloomeister basically oldEmpList is also a list of another list. Therefore I a have to stream and filter the list to update/add items on this sub list. Let assume department is a list. Under each department I have employees and so an employee list. Now I have to filter only for "Accounts" department to update/add employees.

Answer (score 0):

OK here

```
oldEmpList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).addAll(new ArrayList<>(oldEmpList));
```

you are essentially adding oldEmpList to oldEmpList. Is this a typo in your question, or is this how you've accidentally written your code? Because if it's the second, you have your answer right there.

Comment: Question has been updated, that was a typo.